# SignalR-Server throws "Incorrect Content-Type"

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core, signalr-hub

I'm trying to create a working SignalR example with a console app as my client before I move to the necessary one (Android), but I face a little odd problem. My server is ASP.NET 5 (DNX Core 5.0), the server library is SignalR.Server 3.0.0-rc1-final.

This is my client code so far:

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var connection = new HubConnection("http://127.0.0.1:5000/");
    var myHub = connection.CreateHubProxy("TestHub");

    connection.Start().ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(task.Exception.GetBaseException());
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        }

    }).Wait();

    myHub.Invoke<string>("Send", "Hello World!").ContinueWith(task => {
        if (task.IsFaulted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(task.Exception.GetBaseException());
        }
        else {
            Console.WriteLine(task.Result);
        }
    });
}
```

The `connection.Start()` method works, but when trying to invoke `Send()`, I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Incorrect Content-Type:
>       at Microsoft.AspNet.Http.Features.Internal.FormFeature.d__12.MoveNext()
>       ...

My first thought was to try and add the Content-Type header to the connection:

```
connection.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
```

But that yields in the following error on the next connect/invoke attempt:

> Misused header name. Make sure request headers are used with
>   HttpRequestMessage, response headers with HttpResponseMessage, and
>   content headers with HttpContent objects.

Moreover, in the server log I see it's already `application/json`, so I'm a bit confused about this exception.

This is the hub on my server, but it's not really relevant because it doesn't reach `Send` method.

```
[HubName("TestHub")]
public class TestHub : Hub
{
    public string Send(string message)
    {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong? I'll be grateful for any help/idea, thanks.

Comment: While I haven't used SignalR with Asp.Net 5 in the recent weeks, I know that they are not yet compatible, and SignalR 3 will not be a part of Asp.Net 5 release in early 2016. If I have the time, I will try to see if I can get it working, but as I said, they don't yet work. Best of luck!

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if the AspNet.SignalR.Client 2.2 which you are probably using is fully compatible with Server 3.0. However for 4.5.1 I've got it working after adding websocket support to the web server (Kestrel).
In project.json:

```
Microsoft.AspNet.WebSockets.Server":  "1.0.0-rc1-final",
```

In Startup.cs:

```
app.UseWebSockets();
```

You can also use the native cpp client which is still in an early development stage. https://github.com/aspnet/SignalR-Client-Cpp (Appears to only support websockets at the moment).